# Where are temporary hit points mentioned in the PHB?

Tags: dnd-5e, books, temporary-hit-points

Where are temporary hit points mentioned in the PHB?

I can't find it in the *Player's Handbook*.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Is there something specific about Temp HP that you're unable to find or can you just not find the section in the PHB at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried looking in the index?

*Hit points, Temporary* indicates you're looking for page 198.

(*Temporary hit points* also works, but it just redirects you to *Hit points, Temporary*.  I don't know why it doesn't just tell you the page number.)

Comment: I've never written a large guide, but I imagine it is to simplify life while the book is still being edited. If enough content is added to shift a section one or two pages, then you would have to remember to updated multiple entries in the index.

Comment: Probably, though typically you don't add index numbers until the rest of the book is done. And it makes sense if it's sending you to another index entry that has a lot of pages listed -- it just drives me nuts that about half the index entries are redirections to other index entries that then only have a single page listed anyway. It would've been less text to just tell me the page number I wanted in the first place!